# intellij v12 leda, jsLint is picking up javascript errors in my JSP

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, jslint

It is incorrectly detecting a jsLint error in my JSP file, but it shouldn't because cos its not javascript :

[image]

Comment: @BartKiers I thought there may be a setting somewhere to change

Comment: Ah, I see, then I misunderstood your intent...

Comment: @BartKiers my intent is to get jsLint working correctly. It might not be possible as I am using the pre-release version ... submitted anyway. Back to v11.1.3 for me